# I want to know how can is shorten this code and make it look more proper

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know if the code I wrote can be shortened further, I was practicing and I came up to a task which asks you to return a boolean value, this is what the question says:

> Given two strings, return True if either of the strings appears at the
>   very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences
>   (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive").
>   Note: s.lower() returns the lowercase version of a string.

```
def end_other(a, b):
  x = len(b)
  n = a[-x:]
  y = len(a)
  m = b[-y:]
  if b.lower() == n.lower() or a.lower() == m.lower() :
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

The Code is working properly but I wondered **if it can be shortened more** so it looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
def end_other(a, b):
  n = a[-len(b):]
  m = b[-len(a):]
  return b.lower() == n.lower() or a.lower == m.lower()
```

I removed variables `x` and `y` because they are used just one time and then I also remove the `if-else` statement because it's unnecessary, in fact you can just return the result of the comparison instead of checking it's result and returning it a second time.

Comment: Thanks, it looks far better than before